# What's the performance difference between using Object.keys and lodash _.keys()

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any performance difference between using ES6 `Object.keys` and `lodash _.keys()`?

Or what is the benefit of using one against another?

Recently I am considering which one to use is best practice, does anyone knows what goes under the hoods of each? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using lodash in your project , use _.keys .or else se Object.keys .both are good

Comment: You can see it in action over https://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-underscore-keys/3.

Answer (score 8):

The library method `_.keys` is written in Javascript, not native code - when both native code and a custom function can accomplish X, native code is almost always faster, because it's built into the browser and written on a lower-level (like in C++):

```js
const obj = [...new Array(50)];
const p0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) {
  _.keys(obj);
}
const p1 = performance.now();
console.log('lodash', p1 - p0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

```js
const obj = [...new Array(50)];
const p0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) {
  Object.keys(obj);
}
const p1 = performance.now();
console.log('Object.keys', p1 - p0);
```

That said, worrying about such optimizations is *usually* not important - often, if your script has a bottleneck, it'll very likely be somewhere else. Avoid premature optimization. If your current codebase uses `_.keys` and you don't repeatedly call `_.keys` huge numbers of times, it's probably not something to worry about - you might consider sticking with your codebase's current style, whichever it is, for now, unless / until you run into performance issues.

Another difference is that `Object.keys` is an ES5 method. If you have to support *extraordinarily ancient* browsers, they may not be able to use `Object.keys` without a polyfill (and a polyfill would likely have similar performance to the Lodash implementation).